# Finding the minimum number of calls on a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, dynamic-programming

I was asked this question in an interview and struggled to answer it correctly in the time allotted. Nonetheless, I thought it was an interesting problem, and I hadn't seen it before.

Suppose you have a tree where the root can call (on the phone) each of it's children, when a child receives the call, he can call each of his children, etc. The problem is that each call must be done in a number of rounds, and we need to minimize the number of rounds it takes to make the calls. For example, suppose you have the following tree:

> ```
>    A
>   / \
>  /   \
>  B    D
>  |
>  |
>  C
> ```

One solution is for A to call D in round one, A to call B in round two, and B to call C in round three. The optimal solution is for A to call B in round one, and A to call D and B to call C in round two.

Note that A cannot call both B and D in the same round, nor can any node call more than one of its children in the same round. However, multiple nodes with a different parent can call simultaneously. For example, given the tree:

> ```
>       A
>     / | \
>    /  |  \
>    B  C   D
>   /\      |
>  /  \     |
> E   F     G
> ```

We can have a sequence (where - separates rounds), such as:

> A B - B E, A D - B F, A C, D G

(A calls B first round, B calls E and A calls D second, ...)

I'm assuming some type of dynamic programming can be used, but I'm not sure which direction to take this in. My initial inclination is to use DFS to order the longest path from the root to leaves in decreasing order, but when it comes to the nodes actually making calls, I'm not sure how we can achieve optimality given any tree, not how we can output the paths that the optimal calls would make (i.e. in the first example we could output

> A B - B C, A D

Comment: @AliAmiri I don't see how we can greedily select the best path. Can you elaborate?

Comment: for every round and every node select one of its child that have the must children. I think this will solve the problem, but I'm not sure if its efficient or not?!

Comment: @AliAmiri you can't just greedily take a path of unknown length, because it can lead to a sub-optimal solution. The length from root to leaf on the tree for any path isn't known beforehand, so I was thinking we could us DP and DFS to compute path lengths.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this could get the optimal solution:

1. suppose the value of 'calls' for each of leaves is 1
2. for each node get the value of calls for all of his children and rank them according to their 'calls' value
3. consider rank of each child as 'ranks'
4. to compute the value of 'calls' for each node loop over his children (after computing their ranks) and find the maximum value of 'calls' + 'ranks'
5. 'calls' value of the root node is the answer

It's sorta dynamic programming on trees and you can implement it recursively like this:

```
int f(node v)
{
   int s = 0;
   for each u in v.children
   {
      d[u] = f(u)
   }
   sort d and rank its values in r (r for the maximum u would be 1)
   for each u in v.children
   {
      s = max(s, d[u] + r[u] + 1)
   }
   return s
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: How would you even implement step 1? How do you "start from leaves...?" Usually a tree is given as a pointer to the root and pointers to its children.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to do that in this order! You can implement it recursively starting from the root. I described the way it works, but you don't need to see it in this way. In your recursive function, when you reach a leaf, return 1 for example.

Comment: Good but for two little things: leaves make 0 calls, not 1; and if ranks start from 1 then change `d[u] + r[u] + 1` to just `d[u] + r[u]`.